# Friction in physics engine help

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

Ok i know this is sort of a non specific question but i am making a verlet integration physics engine for a game similar to, for example angry birds. I am writing a practice engine just to get the jist of it (credits for simpler c++ version go to Benedikt Bitterli) and no matter what i do i cant figure out how to implement friction. I posted the main collision and caluculation methods below if someone could at least tell me where or in which method i should add something and the name of the techneque or somthing.

```
private void updateVerlet() {
    float tempX;
    float tempY;

    for (int b = 0; b < bodies.size(); b++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bodies.get(b).vertices.size(); i++) {
            Vertex v = bodies.get(b).vertices.get(i);
            tempX = v.x;
            tempY = v.y;
            v.x += v.x - v.ox + v.accx * timestep * timestep;
            v.y += v.y - v.oy + v.accy * timestep * timestep;
            v.ox = tempX;
            v.oy = tempY;
        }
    }
}



private void updateEdges() {
    for (int b = 0; b < bodies.size(); b++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bodies.get(b).edges.size(); i++) {
            Edge e = bodies.get(b).edges.get(i);

            float distX = e.v2.x - e.v1.x;
            float distY = e.v2.y - e.v1.y;

            float dist = (float)Math.hypot(distX, distY);
            float diff = dist - e.length;

            float len = 1f / (float)Math.hypot(distX, distY);// Normalize with (float)Math.hypot(distX, distY); again????
            distX *= len;
            distY *= len;

            e.v1.x += distX * diff * 0.5;
            e.v1.y += distY * diff * 0.5;
            e.v2.x -= distX * diff * 0.5;
            e.v2.y -= distY * diff * 0.5;
        }
    }
}
private void iterateCollisions() {
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {

        // Temporary solution to prevent bodies from falling out of the screen
        for (int b = 0; b < bodies.size(); b++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bodies.get(b).vertices.size(); i++) {
                bodies.get(b).vertices.get(i).x = Math.max(Math.min(bodies.get(b).vertices.get(i).x, (float)screenWidth), 0.0f);
                bodies.get(b).vertices.get(i).y = Math.max(Math.min(bodies.get(b).vertices.get(i).y, (float)screenHeight), 0.0f);
            }
        }

        updateEdges();

        for (int b = 0; b < bodies.size(); b++) {
            bodies.get(b).calculateCenter();
        }

        for (int b1 = 0; b1 < bodies.size(); b1++) {
            for (int b2 = 0; b2 < bodies.size(); b2++) {
                if (bodies.get(b1) != bodies.get(b2)) {
                    if (bodiesOverlap(bodies.get(b1), bodies.get(b2))) {
                        if (detectCollision(bodies.get(b1), bodies.get(b2))) {
                            processCollision();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
private boolean bodiesOverlap(PhysicsBody b1, PhysicsBody b2) {
    return
    (b1.minX <= b2.maxX) &&
    (b1.minY <= b2.maxY) &&
    (b1.maxX >= b2.minX) &&
    (b2.maxY >= b1.minY);
}

private boolean detectCollision(PhysicsBody b1, PhysicsBody b2) {
    float minDistance = 10000.0f;
    Edge e;

    for (int i = 0; i < b1.edges.size() + b2.edges.size(); i++) {
        if (i < b1.edges.size()) {
            e = b1.edges.get(i);
        } else {
            e= b2.edges.get(i - b1.edges.size());
        }

        if (!e.boundary)
            continue;

        axis.x = e.v1.y - e.v2.y;
        axis.y = e.v2.x - e.v1.x;

        float len = 1f / (float)Math.hypot(axis.x, axis.y);
        axis.x *= len;
        axis.y *= len;

        MinMax dataA = b1.projectToAxis(axis);
        MinMax dataB = b2.projectToAxis(axis);

        float distance = intervalDistance(dataA, dataB);

        if (distance > 0f)
            return false;
        else if (Math.abs(distance) < minDistance) {
            minDistance = Math.abs(distance);

            CollisionInfo.normalX = axis.x;
            CollisionInfo.normalY = axis.y;
            CollisionInfo.e = e;
        }
    }

    CollisionInfo.depth = minDistance;

    if (CollisionInfo.e.parent != b2) {
        PhysicsBody temp = b2;
        b2 = b1;
        b1 = temp;
    }

    float diffX = b1.centerX - b2.centerX;
    float diffY = b1.centerY - b2.centerY;
    float mult = CollisionInfo.normalX * diffX + CollisionInfo.normalY * diffY;

    if (mult < 0) {
        CollisionInfo.normalX = 0 - CollisionInfo.normalX;
        CollisionInfo.normalY = 0 - CollisionInfo.normalY;
    }

    minDistance = 10000.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < b1.vertices.size(); i++) {
        diffX = b1.vertices.get(i).x - b2.centerX;
        diffY = b1.vertices.get(i).y - b2.centerY;
        float distance = CollisionInfo.normalX * diffX + CollisionInfo.normalX * diffY;

        if (distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            CollisionInfo.v = b1.vertices.get(i);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void processCollision() {
    Vertex v1 = CollisionInfo.e.v1;
    Vertex v2 = CollisionInfo.e.v2;

    float collisionVectorX = CollisionInfo.normalX * CollisionInfo.depth;
    float collisionVectorY = CollisionInfo.normalY * CollisionInfo.depth;

    float t;
    if (Math.abs(v1.x - v2.x) > Math.abs(v1.y - v2.y)) {
        t = (CollisionInfo.v.x - collisionVectorX - v1.x) / (v2.x - v1.x);
    }
    else {
        t = (CollisionInfo.v.y - collisionVectorY - v1.y) / (v2.y - v1.y);
    }

    float lambda = 1.0f / (t * t + (1 - t) * (1 - t));
    float edgeMass = t * v2.parent.mass + (1f - t) * v1.parent.mass;
    float invCollisionMass = 1.0f / (edgeMass + CollisionInfo.v.parent.mass);

    float ratio1 = CollisionInfo.v.parent.mass * invCollisionMass;
    float ratio2 = edgeMass*invCollisionMass;

    v1.x -= collisionVectorX * ((1 - t) * ratio1 * lambda);
    v1.y -= collisionVectorY * (( 1 - t) * ratio1 * lambda);
    v2.x -= collisionVectorX * (t * ratio1 * lambda);
    v2.y -= collisionVectorY * (t * ratio1 * lambda);

    CollisionInfo.v.x += collisionVectorX * ratio2;
    CollisionInfo.v.y += collisionVectorY * ratio2;
}
```

Comment: Friction is just modeled as a force. Add the friction vector into your acceleration vector when computing the location.

Comment: @gabe: I dont need air resistance, that would be easy. i need friction with other objects.

Comment: i have tried reading into this but the equations are extremely complicated and i have only taken freshman algebra so far

Comment: @heandel: i put all the main calculations so maybye someone would know in which one the friction calculation would go

Comment: Some complain that there is too much code, but I don't have enough code, comments and knowledge to understand what's going on.  I'm confused because there does not seem to be any velocities anywhere.  Also in `updateVerlet`, there a 0.5 missing in front of the `v.acc_ * timestep * timestep`.

Comment: stas - this question isn't answerable in its current form, because the answer is the length of a physics book (the knowledge which you must acquire to know where to put this). Since you don't yet have the math background, any programming answer we give you won't make any sense at this point. See if you can hit up a cool physics teacher/professor and see if they can give you a shortcut/specific training on the friction problem. I think if you get that, it will become obvious where to put the friction code.

Comment: By inspection, your simulation seems to be of objects moving around in zero-gravity and bouncing off each other. The friction you're interested in sounds like either *sliding* friction (which won't happen in that kind of world) or the "friction" which causes two colliding objects to emerge from a collision more slowly than they went in (in which case you should tweak `lambda` in `processCollision`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, friction on the bottom world boundary
for every particle, limit horizontal movement.

```
if(Particle.Y >= world_height) { Particle.OldX = Particle.OldX - (Particle.OldX - Particle.X)/2; }
```